# Is it possible to render QuickTime movies on iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, quicktime, h.264

Any methods would be useful! (to clarify: by render, I mean create, not playback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out [ffmpeg4iphone](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg4iphone/), which should allow you to generate quicktime compatible movies.